# Concatenating String & Variable With Dot Notation = Error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, mongoose, grunt-contrib-uglify

I am Uglifying some Angular, and getting an error hitting a block where I am concatenating a string and a variable... for MongoDB I need to reference the array index using dot notation...

```
['images.exterior.' + index]: content,
```

Error message is: 
Warning: Uglification failed. Unexpected token: string (images.exterior.).

Weird issue for me where I don't even know where to start looking? Can anyone recommend another way to concatenate that string and variable as a key?

[UPDATE 1]

Tried concatenating and using the variable which is the same as 'images.exterior.0': content,

But it sends an empty request with Mongoose:

Mongoose: inventories.findAndModify({}) [] { '$setOnInsert': { __v: 0 } } { new: true, upsert: true, remove: false }

The variable is not getting replaced with the string value... If I used a coded string of 'images.exterior.0' it works.......

Thank you
John

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping up the concatenation made this pass through Uglify, and still work with Mongoose.

```
var holder = {};
holder["images.interior."+ index] = content;
```

Then became...

```
inventory.update({id:$scope.item._id}, {
    $set: holder
}).$promise.then(function(data){
    $scope.item.images.interior = data.images.interior;
});
```

Comment: Maybe you can transpile before minifying? You can also try UglifyJS's harmony branch, maybe that will work better

Comment: Great direction @IonutCostica, that is what someone from Uglify mentioned on GitHub.